# SQL Over Partition By Over Partition By

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have the following code and it works fine when I am referencing one '`leadno`' as it returns the highest sum of individual products

```
select t.*
from (Select t2.leadno, t1.quoteno, t1.cn_ref, sum(t1.qty/100) as 't_qty',
             ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By t1.cn_ref order by sum(qty/100) desc) as RN 
      From dba.quotelne t1 INNER JOIN
           dba.quotehdr t2
           ON t1.quoteno = t2.quoteno
      Where leadno = 31665 and t1.statusflag = 'A' and t2.statusflag = 'A' 
      Group By t2.leadno, t1.quoteno, t1.cn_ref
     ) t
where rn = 1
```

But when I add more that one `leadno` it returns doesn't return all the `quoteno` it only returns the values of the highest `sum(qty/100)`, so Is there a way to run a `ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By` in a `ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By)`

I hope this makes sense, but if not I will try to explain, a little further, each 'lead' may have one or more 'quotes' against it. Each 'quote' will have a number of products listed. These may be duplicated (hence why I am using `sum(qty/100)` What I need to happen is all `leadno` to be displayed, the unique `cn_ref` and the highest quantity `RN = 1` against the `leadno`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but I think you need to put the leadno in the Partition to accomplish what you need:

```
select t.*
    from (Select t2.leadno, t1.quoteno, t1.cn_ref, sum(t1.qty/100) as 't_qty',
         ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By t2.leadno, t1.cn_ref order by sum(qty/100) desc) as RN 
      From dba.quotelne t1 INNER JOIN
           dba.quotehdr t2
       ON t1.quoteno = t2.quoteno
      Where leadno = 31665 and t1.statusflag = 'A' and t2.statusflag = 'A' 
      Group By t2.leadno, t1.quoteno, t1.cn_ref
     ) t
where rn = 1
```

Beside that, you shouldn't devide the qty in the order by, it doens't change the order because you devide every value by 100, but the engine has to devide every record before it can create the summary

Answer (score 0):

Why your need to use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY)?

If I understand your needs, you want the the follow values: leadno, cn_ref, max(sum(qty/100))

So, try this query:

```
Select t2.leadno, t1.cn_ref, max(sum(t1.qty/100)) as 't_qty',
  From dba.quotelne t1 INNER JOIN
       dba.quotehdr t2
       ON t1.quoteno = t2.quoteno
  Where leadno = 31665 and t1.statusflag = 'A' and t2.statusflag = 'A' 
  Group By t2.leadno
```

Comment: I tried using 'max(sum(t1.qty/100))' but the system doesn't recognise it.